# Bootstrap NavBar aligin items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i'd like to create a NavBar in Bootstrap. There shoud be a logo, which is at the left side, and some other stuff, which shoud be at the right side.

In the center shoud be a textbox. But how can i do this?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNGFG.png)

Thank you for your help (and sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With `div`

This create a div divided in three columns (left|center|right):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="float-left" src="to/your/img.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 text-center">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <p class="float-right">Right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can style it in css and make it as navbar

### With `nav`

> Suggested by [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```